# Cannot access variable from two scopes outside the current scope?

Tags: c, function, variables, compiler-errors, scope

Some super easy test codes here to elaborate my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void prompt();
void func();

int main() {
    char* arr = "Hello";

    while(1) {
        prompt();
    }

    return 0;
}

void prompt() {
    func();
}

void func() {
    char* data = NULL;
    data = arr;
}
```

So as you can see, I define a variable `arr` in the `main()` function

- and then the code goes inside a `while()` loop,

  - in which it goes inside a function called `prompt()`,

    - in which it goes inside a function called `func()`,

      - in which I want to access the variable `arr` that I defined earlier.

But, when I try to compile this snippet of code (using gcc), I got a error telling me that

> error:'arr' undeclared (first used in this function)`.

Also, I got a warning telling me that

> `warning: unused variable 'arr'`.

So weird...Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have 2 options**

> 1. Make the variable arr global (as mentioned by Sourav)
> 2. Pass the pointer to the arr variable to the prompt() function, and then also to func(). You can then use it in func().

Which one you choose depends on the task on hand and the complexity of the project.

If it is a simple project and this is a one off, then you may use a global.

However, as your project complexity increases and especially if you are going to be doing this at multiple locations, I would strongly suggest that you take the effort and go by **option 2**.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `arr` is having `main()` function (block) scope <sup>#</sup>. Inside `func()`, there is no existance of `arr`.

If you need to access `arr` from `func()`, you need to make it global.

---

<sup>(#)Don't confuse with lifetime</sup>

Comment: how to make it global?

Comment: @walkerlala put `char* arr = "Hello";` outside `main()`

Comment: Why won't the compiler automatically find variable outside the current function? I mean, the current function `A` is called by another function `B`, so isn't it reasonable that in function `A` I can use the variable outside (one frame outside it)?

Comment: I can access a variable when I am in a `while` loop, which is also a block as a function. Then why can't I access it in a function?

Comment: Inside of a `while` loop, you are still inside the same function, so variables defined in that function are still viewable.  As soon as you call another function, any variables defined in the calling functions are inaccessible.